# Filtering fields from a RetrieveAPIView in the serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a model structure where an `Outage` has many `Product` and each `Product` is associated with a `Client`.

When I get a list of outages for a client, I can use the `OutageSerializer` to ensure that the products listed in the outage belong to the client like so:

```
class OutageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Outage

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OutageSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        client_id = self.context.get("client_id")
        if client_id:
            if 'products' in self.fields and \ 
                    hasattr(self.fields['products'], 'child_relation'):
                product_ids = ClientManager(client_id).client_products().\
                    values_list('pk', flat=True)
                self.fields['products'].child_relation.queryset = \
                    self.fields['products'].child_relation.queryset.\
                        filter(id__in=product_ids)
```

However, if I'm only getting a single outage via a `RetrieveAPIView`, the `child_relation` attribute is no longer available, and so I have to look to other means.

Currently, I'm checking the length of *args and placing a filter of the products field there, like so:

```
class OutageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Outage

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OutageSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        client_id = self.context.get("client_id")
        if client_id:
            if 'products' in self.fields:
                if hasattr(self.fields['products'], 'child_relation'):
                    product_ids = ClientManager(client_id).client_products().\
                        values_list('pk', flat=True)
                    self.fields['products'].child_relation.queryset = \
                        self.fields['products'].child_relation.queryset.\
                            filter(id__in=product_ids)
                elif len(args) == 1 and hasattr(args[0], 'products'):
                    product_ids = ClientManager(client_id).client_products().\
                        values_list('pk', flat=True)
                    args[0].products = \
                        args[0].products.filter(id__in=products_ids)
```

Keep in mind that that the products field is not the only field I want to filter.

Currently, the API is only used for GETs.

Whilst this method "works", it seems a bit messy.  Is there a preferred standard way of filtering list fields for `RetrieveAPIView`s?

Answer (score 0):

If `Product` has FKs to `Outage` and `Client` with related_name `products` than you can use `SerializerMethodField`.

```
class OutageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_products(self, outage):
        products_qs = outage.products.filter(client=self.context['request'].client)
        return ProductSerialzier(products_qs, many=True).data
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me as a long term solution. Whilst I can adjust to do similar filtering on the products, using the ClientManager to get valid products for the client, I have an optional client_id in the context, not a mandatory client in the request context. Additionally, this forces me to use a particular serializer for the product, preventing me from extending OutageSerializer and providing a different product serializer for those sub classes.